# db2: select from table without replacement

Tags: db2

Hi I would just like to ask a simple question - is there a way in DB2, to select a row from a table (whether that be based on a join or selecting a random row), and then select from the same table again where choosing the last, or any previous rows cannot be selected.

I am thinking I have to loop my code through each row in the table and delete each row I select, but would be interested if anyone has an alternative solution. No code needed but rather describe another approach.

Thanks,

Arron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this is to declare a cursor to select all rows from the table then process the
cursor one row at a time. Each row will be selected exactly 1 time (this is pretty much what a cursor is all about).

I suspect that is not the answer you were looking for. You most likely have at least two other constrains on this
selection problem:

- You do not want, or cannot, have a single cursor open until the entire table has been processed
- You want to have some sort of "randomness" with respect to the order in which rows are selected

The problem of not being able to open and process the entire table under a single cursor can be solved by
maintaining some sort of "state" information between selections. The "state" can be used to determine whether a row
is still eligible for selection on subsequent inquiries. You might add another column to the table to hold the "selected"
state of that row. When a row is inserted its "selected" state is set to "no". On each select operation the state
of the selected row is updated to "yes". The predicate to select new rows then needs to have a `WHEN SELECT_STATE = 'no'`
added to it to disqualify previously selected rows. If you cannot change the structure of the table you are selecting
from, then add a second table having the same primary key as the selection table plus the "selected" indicator then join
these tables to obtain the required state information.

Another approach is to delete a row once it has been selected.

These or some similar type of state management can be used to solve the selection eligibility problem.

If you need to introduce randomness into the selection process (i.e. make it difficult go guess what
the next row to be selected will be), then you have a very different problem to solve. If this is the case
please ask a new question outlining the approximate size of you table (how many rows) and what the key structure
is (eg. a number between 1 and 100000, a 30 character name etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cursor, and use the 'delete where current of' feature called positioned-delete. For more information:

- http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000939.html
- http://mysite.verizon.net/Graeme_Birchall/cookbook/DB2V97CK.PDF page 55